yahoo finance indicators and growth rate calcualtions
I am trying to create growth rates for thirty days after download the data from yahoo finance. I used the following codes and a function but my output prints the same numbers for all days ( 1-30) days of growth. any help is appreciated.
# Extracting data from yahoo finance
    
import pandas as pd
import requests
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import datetime

symbols = ['MSFT', 'HD', 'TSLA']
stocks_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})
symbols_daily = yf.download(symbols,
                 period = "max",
                 interval = "1d")
for i,ticker in enumerate(symbols):
  print(i,ticker)

  # Work with stock prices
  historyPrices = yf.download(tickers = ticker,
                     period = "max",
                     interval = "1d")

  # generate features for historical prices, and what we want to predict
  historyPrices['Ticker'] = ticker
  historyPrices['Year']= historyPrices.index.year
  historyPrices['Month'] = historyPrices.index.month
  historyPrices['Weekday'] = historyPrices.index.weekday
  historyPrices['Date'] = historyPrices.index.date

  if stocks_df.empty:
    stocks_df = historyPrices
  else:
    stocks_df = pd.concat([stocks_df, historyPrices], ignore_index=True)

and I created the function:
# function to create growth
def get_growth_df(df:pd.DataFrame)->pd.DataFrame:
  for i in range(1, 31):
    df['future_growth_'+str(i)+'d'] = df['Adj Close'].shift(-i) / df['Adj Close']
    GROWTH_KEYS = [k for k in df.columns if k.startswith('future_growth_')]
  return df[GROWTH_KEYS]

get_growth_df(historyPrices).describe()

it gives me the same values for each of the thirty days.
I am expecting something like this for each of the thirty days growth, i.e. I expect output with the different values of mean, std, min, 25%, 50%, 75% quantiles:




future_growth_1d
future_growth_2d




count
100
100


mean
0.99
0.83


std
0.15
0.12


min
0.29
0.29


25%
0.93
-.0.5


50%
1.03
0.95


75%
1.522
1.01


100%
1.6
1.8




in fact, I mistyped it. it actually is 'i' in my original code but it does not fix the problem. Thanks.

You are overwriting the growth values for each day in the loop, resulting in all days having the same values.
Here is how to do this:
import pandas as pd
import requests
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import datetime

symbols = ['MSFT', 'HD', 'TSLA']
stocks_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})
symbols_daily = yf.download(symbols,
                 period = "max",
                 interval = "1d")
for i,ticker in enumerate(symbols):
  print(i,ticker)

  historyPrices = yf.download(tickers = ticker,
                     period = "max",
                     interval = "1d")

  historyPrices['Ticker'] = ticker
  historyPrices['Year']= historyPrices.index.year
  historyPrices['Month'] = historyPrices.index.month
  historyPrices['Weekday'] = historyPrices.index.weekday
  historyPrices['Date'] = historyPrices.index.date

  if stocks_df.empty:
    stocks_df = historyPrices
  else:
    stocks_df = pd.concat([stocks_df, historyPrices], ignore_index=True)
    
def get_growth_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    growth_df = pd.DataFrame()  
    for i in range(1, 31):
        growth_df['future_growth_' + str(i) + 'd'] = df['Adj Close'].shift(-i) / df['Adj Close']
    return growth_df
growth_df = get_growth_df(historyPrices)
print(growth_df.describe())


which gives
       future_growth_1d  future_growth_2d  future_growth_3d  future_growth_4d  \
count       3485.000000       3484.000000       3483.000000       3482.000000   
mean           1.001999          1.004002          1.006037          1.008135   
std            0.035862          0.050936          0.062556          0.072825   
min            0.789372          0.733607          0.660825          0.644403   
25%            0.983968          0.975536          0.971718          0.966988   
50%            1.001210          1.003070          1.004293          1.005382   
75%            1.019175          1.029505          1.039817          1.045851   
max            1.243951          1.375874          1.573759          1.581697   

       future_growth_5d  future_growth_6d  future_growth_7d  future_growth_8d  \
count       3481.000000       3480.000000       3479.000000       3478.000000   
mean           1.010306          1.012427          1.014515          1.016621   
std            0.081955          0.090146          0.097482          0.104642   
min            0.569541          0.559745          0.594112          0.513476   
25%            0.962229          0.958083          0.954501          0.952468   
50%            1.006870          1.008695          1.009707          1.010488   
75%            1.052710          1.059553          1.063870          1.069472   
max            1.564756          1.653522          1.661863          1.648352   

       future_growth_9d  future_growth_10d  ...  future_growth_21d  \
count       3477.000000        3476.000000  ...        3465.000000   
mean           1.018717           1.020812  ...           1.045285   
std            0.111629           0.118306  ...           0.187711   
min            0.498551           0.481948  ...           0.420806   
25%            0.948485           0.947469  ...           0.924693   
50%            1.011687           1.013544  ...           1.022052   
75%            1.074856           1.081088  ...           1.128908   
max            1.691109           1.704861  ...           2.154883   

       future_growth_22d  future_growth_23d  future_growth_24d  \
count        3464.000000        3463.000000        3462.000000   
mean            1.047560           1.049827           1.052075   
std             0.193157           0.198435           0.203717   
min             0.451508           0.449279           0.470774   
25%             0.923134           0.920435           0.919296   
50%             1.021298           1.022292           1.022174   
75%             1.131996           1.138487           1.141386   
max             2.121730           2.187785           2.167901   

       future_growth_25d  future_growth_26d  future_growth_27d  \
count        3461.000000        3460.000000        3459.000000   
mean            1.054362           1.056683           1.059002   
std             0.208943           0.214268           0.219353   
min             0.466464           0.468338           0.482869   
25%             0.916874           0.916088           0.914912   
50%             1.021142           1.021489           1.021616   
75%             1.147301           1.157854           1.160344   
max             2.198247           2.306711           2.348946   

       future_growth_28d  future_growth_29d  future_growth_30d  
count        3458.000000        3457.000000        3456.000000  
mean            1.061295           1.063603           1.065939  
std             0.224028           0.228895           0.233832  
min             0.482295           0.484973           0.407210  
25%             0.913807           0.912978           0.912492  
50%             1.024461           1.025763           1.025216  
75%             1.163379           1.167726           1.172320  
max             2.427503           2.420048           2.548036  


It worked. thanks! I think we don't need: symbols_daily = yf.download(symbols,
period = "max",
interval = "1d")
